# How to touch next button in Bluesacks with MonkeyRunner

Tags: java, android, python, monkeyrunner, bluestacks

Please refer to the  attached image. How can I push the "Next" button in the `Instagram` Application with `MonkeyRunner`?

Any Suggestions ?

My code

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

package_sq = 'com.instest'
activity_sq = 'com.instest.MainActivity'

runComponent = package_sq + '/' + activity_sq

device.startActivity(component = runComponent)

device.press('KEYCODE_FORWARD', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

[image]